# ngIf- Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: false'. Current value: 'ngIf: true'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

How to call method from one component to another when it has no parent child relation?

I have 2 sibling components and as below:

header.ts

```
private postValues() {
   this._PartService.PostDataValues(this.search)
       .subscribe(result => {
       })
}
```

part.ts

```
this._PartService.getMasterData()
    .subscribe(result => {
    })
```

In this case I need to call `postValues()` method into `getMasterData()` to get some description values, and it has no parent and child communication.

Comment: new a instance of header in part service then call the postValues method of it.

Comment: sorry I didn't get you..How to do that

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54784980/angular-7-communication-through-service-subscribe-method-called-twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to trigger a sibling component method directly, but there is a way to trigger sibling component event using **`import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';`**

**I use this approach to pass data to sibling component but it's work as well if you trigger event.**

First You Create Service, Service that I call it **`DataService.ts`**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private triggerEventMsg = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  triggerEvent = this.triggerEventMsg.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  triggerEvent(val: boolean) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

}
```

Now One Component Trigger another Component, For now, Com1 trigger Com2 event.

Com1 trigger DataService triggerEvent with pass boolean value.

**`Com1.component.ts`**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-com1',
  template: `
    {{message}}
    <button (click)="newMessage()">New Message</button>
  `
})
export class Com1 implements OnInit {

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

 com1ClickEvent() {
    this.data.triggerEvent(true);
  }

}
```

Com2 Observe that variable when data change the method trigger in Com2 Component.

**`Com2.component.ts`**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-com2',
  template: `
    <p>Com2</p>
  `
})
export class Com2 implements OnInit {



  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.triggerEventMsg.subscribe(message => {
        // Do What ever you want.

     })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to use

```
    ngAfterViewChecked(){
      this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    }
```

in the component that you get the error

Answer (score 0):

communicate to component which are not parent-child. So I'm communicating it through service

service.ts

```
value=false; 
search: EventEmitter < boolean > = new EventEmitter();
toggle() {
   this.value = !this.value;
   this.search.emit(this.value);
}
```

search.ts

```
submit():void{
  this.service.toggle();
}
```

Home.ts

```
ngOnInit() {    
   this.service.change.subscribe(value => {
           //some code here
    }
}
```