# Angular 7 Communication through service subscribe method called twice

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7

I'm using angular, trying to communicate to a component that is not parent-child. So I'm communicating it through service

service.ts

```
Istoggle=false; 
@Output() change: EventEmitter < boolean > = new EventEmitter();
toggle() {
    this.Istoggle= !this.Istoggle;
    this.toggle.emit(this.Istoggle);
}
```

search.ts

```
submit():void{
  this.service.toggle();
}
```

Home.ts

```
ngOnInit() {    
   this.service.change.subscribe(_toggle=> {
           //some code here
    }
}
```

so when I click on submit in Home component toggle subscribe get hit twice

Comment: can you add a live example base of you example ? https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Reference from https://medium.com/@mirokoczka/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb @malbarmawi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as I see you have 3 fields with exact the same name in your service. 2 of them are missed. you could do

```
value=false; 
search: EventEmitter < boolean > = new EventEmitter();
toggle() {
   this.value = !this.value;
   this.search.emit(this.value);
}
```

in your service and in component:

```
ngOnInit() {    
  this.service.search.subscribe(value => {
       //some code here
  }
}
```

note that I removed @Output() decorator. it is used only inside components just for parent-child communication.

Comment: could you please provide a stackblitz with your case?

Comment: Sorry I can't. @Andrei