# How to call a function from another component [Angular]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587732/how-to-call-another-components-function-in-angular2) question is very much similar to mine but doesn't answers my question. In my case, the two components are stand-alone, that means they ain't parent-child to each other. They're separate and at same directory level. That's why my problem is different from the rest. I tried using:

1. @ViewChild();
2. @Output() ....EventEmitter()

But I'm still getting an error in `navbar.component.ts`:

> ERROR TypeError: "this.articles is undefined"

My first component is `NavBar` and my second component is `Articles`

So the scenarioa is, `pressed()` method of `NavBar` have to call `callSearch(arg)` method of `Articles`.

Here is my **navbar.component.ts**

```
import { ..., ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ArticlesComponent } from '../articles/articles.component';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  text='something';

  @ViewChild(ArticlesComponent, {static: false}) articles: ArticlesComponent;

  constructor() { }

  /*  This method is called on click event from HTML page*/
  pressed(text: string) {
    this.articles.callSearch(text);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**navbar.component.html**

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <button class="btn" (click)="pressed(text)">Search</button>
</li>
```

And here is the component whose method I want to call from NavBar.

**articles.component.ts**

```
import { ... } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class ArticlesComponent implements OnInit {

  articles = [];
  filteredArticles=[];

  constructor(...) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    ...
  }

  /*  this is called from navbar typescript and it will call SearchFunction below*/
  callSearch(text: string) {
    this.SearchFunction(text);
  }

  SearchFunction(text: string) {
    this.filteredArticles=(this.articles.filter(e => {
      /* some logic*/
    }));
  }
}
```

**articles.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let article of filteredArticles; let i = index;">
  <div class="card text-center">
    <div class="card-body">
      <!-- card design related html -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please correct me.

PS: Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fgge3w).

Comment: Can you include the html of the components?

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54784980/angular-7-communication-through-service-subscribe-method-called-twice) your question

Comment: _"the two components are stand-alone, that means they ain't parent-child to each other"_ - then `@ViewChild` can't possibly work. You might want to communicate through their common parent component (if they belong to common parent component), or a service.

Comment: Ok. I'll include HTML here. In fact I'm trying to create stackblitz. that will be more easy for everyone i think.

Comment: Please include the `html` in your question body and a stackblitz would be great as well.

Comment: @mbojko. that's the problem. there's no common service between ten. One isNavbar item and the other is Atricle that reads all articles from mongodb.

Comment: here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tbhdwe)

Comment: @MustafaKunwa. I'm creating a stackblitz. I've seen your solution also. :-) Will get back to you. give me 5 min

Comment: Here is the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fgge3w

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fgge3w

Answer (score 1):

To communicate two components that are not related to each other, you can use a service.

```
    @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class YourService {

    private yourVariable: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();


    public listenYourVariable() {
        return this.yourVariable.asObservable();

    }


    private yourVariableObserver(value : type) {
        this.yourVariable.next(value);
    }
```

You import in yours components where you want use it this service.

```
import{ YourService } from ...
```

In component you want write the data call:

```
this.yourService.yourVariableObserver(yourData);
```

while where you want read the data:

```
 this.yourService.listenYourVariable().subscribe(
    variable => {
      this.data = variable;
      this.callyourFunction();
    }

)
```

Obviously you can simple call the function without pass any value.

Comment: Can you see this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fgge3w

Comment: You create the service how i did and then in navBar component call this.yourService.yourVariableObserver(arg); and in articles this.yourService.listenYourVariable().subscribe(
    variable => {
      const arg = variable;
      this.callSearch(arg)
    }

)

Comment: Sure I'll give it i shot. I appreciate your help. :-)